# installing Luatex in Miktex

Tags: miktex, luatex

How to install Luatex win 32 luatex version in Miktex 2.7, see http://www.luatex.org/download.html , my operating system is Windows XP, it seems that the luatex package is not complete, it doesn't contain some files like .fmt files or something like that. please, if you've experienced the luatex or lualatex installation on windows,  show me  how to do that step by step.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! MikTeX 2.7 is rather obsolete by now. Did you mean to write MikTeX **2.9**? Please advise.

Comment: This is like installing a new Ferrari engine in an old Gran Torino; great car, but bound to break apart with such an engine. I believe that MiKTeX 2.9 runs on Windows XP.

Comment: @egreg: it does run on XP.

Comment: @Mico : Miktex 2.7 but it is always possible to put in it some add-on in the texmf tree ! unfortunately the luatex package is not complete.I think that Something else must be done e.g building the fmt files !  P.Hall

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why won't you step up to version 2.9 of MikTeX?

Comment: @Mico : No problem, i am ready to use version 2.9 but is it really necessary ? P.Hall

Comment: LuaTeX has been available in MiKTeX for many years. However, if you didn't install before and your MiKTeX version is no longer 'current' then you'll have to update your MiKTeX: it's not possible just to 'drop in' the LuaTeX binary from an arbitrary source.